# How to make the \citetitle command include the subtitle as well?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am working with the `biblatex-apa` package, but as I use the `subtitle` field in many references when I feel it is needed, I have encountered the problem that if I cite the title of the work in the document, the subtitle does not appear.

So my question: is there a way to make the `\citetitle` command add the subtitle information as well, or failing that, could a new `\citesubtitle` command be created that cites the subtitle so that I could do something along the lines of `\citetitle{ref}~\citesubtitle{ref}`.

V. Gr.

```
@Book{plant_zeros_1997,
  author    = {Plant, Sadie},
  date      = {1997-09-01},
  isbn      = {978-0385482608},
  langid    = {english},
  pagetotal = {305},
  publisher = {Fourth Estate London},
  subtitle  = {Digital women+ the new technoculture},
  title     = {Zeros + ones:},
  year      = {1997},
}

@Book{cox_speaking_2012,
  author    = {Cox, Geoff and McLean, Alex},
  date      = {2012-11-09},
  foreword  = {Berardi, Franco \enquote{Bifo}},
  isbn      = {9780262018364},
  langid    = {english},
  pagetotal = {168},
  subtitle  = {Coding as Aesthetic and Political Expression},
  title     = {Speaking Code:},
  url       = {https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262018364/speaking-code/},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to modify the `cite:noname` macro, something like:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:noname}{%
  \iffieldundef{labeltitle}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{legmaterial}\OR%
                 \ifentrytype{legadminmaterial}}
      {\let\blx@tempa\bibcplstring% \textcite default
       \let\blx@tempb\bibcplstring% \textcite default
       \iftoggle{apa:inpcite}
         {\iffieldequalstr{type}{execorder}{\let\blx@tempb\bibcpsstring}{}%
          \iffieldequalstr{type}{resolution}{\let\blx@tempa\bibcpsstring}{}%
          \iffieldequalstr{type}{report}{\let\blx@tempa\bibcpsstring\let\blx@tempb\bibcpsstring}{}}
         {}%
       \iffieldundef{source}{}{\blx@tempa{\thefield{source}}}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \iffieldundef{type}{}{\blx@tempb{\thefield{type}}}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield[legmaterialnum]{number}}
      {\ifentrytype{constitution}{\usebibmacro{cite:noname:const}}{}}}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}\addcolon\printfield[citetitle]{subtitle}}}
```